# How to stop opening VSCode every time I open a new iTerm or Terminal window/tab

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, iterm2

For some reason today whenever I open a new window in iTerm or Terminal it opens VSCode for a sec before closing it. Whenever this happens the terminal disappears from my screen and it's really annoying. It is running commands as soon as it opens the new window. The top of iTerm2 displays

`login`

then

`bash`

then finally

`Electron` before it kicks me out and opens VSCode. I installed  luaenv and rbenv today and I tried to comment out the paths in /.zshrc. but it didn't help at all. Do you know what is causing this issue? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. In my ~/.p10k.zsh literally the first line was 'code', which of course is the command to open VSCode. I just commented it out and now it's totally fine. It still displays `login` and then `bash` but it doesn't display `Electron` anymore and doesn't open VSCode every single time anymore.